# Angular 2: How to prevent a form from submitting on keypress enter?

Tags: javascript, angular

I have a form with one field that acts as autocomplete. If the user enters a word and presses enter, the content of the field should be added to a list below the field.

The problem: When the user hits enter, naturally the whole form is being submitted.

I already `return false` on the function that handles the keypress. But the form seems to be submitted even before this function is called.

How do I prevent this from happening?

The basic form:

```
<div id="profileForm">
  <form [formGroup]="profileForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()" method="post" *ngIf="!showSuccessMessage">

    <div class="row">

      <div class="form-group col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
        <label for="first_name">My Skills</label>
        <div class="autocomplete">
          <input formControlName="skill_string" [(ngModel)]="skillString" name="skill_string"
          type="text" class="form-control" id="skill_string" placeholder="Comma separated" (keyup.enter)="skillsHandleEnter(skillString)">
          <ul class="autocomplete-list" *ngIf="skillHints.length > 0">
            <li class="list-item" *ngFor="let skill of skillHints" (click)="addSkillFromAutocomplete(skill)">{{skill}}</li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <div id="skill-cloud" class="tag-cloud">
          <span class="skill-tag tag label label-success" *ngFor="let skill of selectedSkills" (click)="removeSkill(skill)">{{skill}} x</span>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>

    <div class="row">

      <hr>

      <div class="form-group submit-group">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary pull-right" [disabled]="!profileForm.valid">Save</button>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>

  </form>
</div>
```

The basic component (I stripped a lot of the logic for posting it here):

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup, FormBuilder } from '@angular/forms';
import { ActivatedRoute, Router } from '@angular/router';

import { Subscription } from 'rxjs/Rx';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/debounceTime';
import * as _ from 'lodash';

import { MemberService } from '../shared/index';

@Component({
  moduleId: module.id,
  selector: 'signup',
  templateUrl: 'signup.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['signup.component.css']
})
export class SignupComponent implements OnInit {

  private profileForm:FormGroup;
  private validation_errors:Array<any>;
  private selectedSkills:Array<string>;
  private skillHints:Array<string>;
  private skillString:string;

  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private formBuilder: FormBuilder,
    private memberService: MemberService,
    private router: Router ) {

      this.selectedSkills = [];
      this.skillHints = [];
      this.skillString = '';

      // Set up form
      this.profileForm = this.formBuilder.group({
        skill_string: ['']
      });

  }

  ngOnInit(): any {
    // Do something
  }



  updateSelectedSkills(skillString:string):void {
    if(skillString) ) {
      let cleanString = skillString.trim().replace(/[ ]{2,}/g, ' ');
      this.selectedSkills = _.compact(this.selectedSkills.concat(cleanString.split(',')));
      this.skillString = '';
      this.skillHints = [];
    }
  }

  skillsHandleEnter(skillString:string):void {
    console.log("ENTER");
    this.updateSelectedSkills(skillString);
    return false;
  }

  autocompleteSkills(term:string):void {
    this.memberService.autocompleteSkills(term).subscribe(
      res => {
        this.skillHints = [];
        for(let i = 0; i < res.data.length; i++) {
          this.skillHints.push(res.data[i].name);
        }
      }
    );
  }

  addSkillFromAutocomplete(skillString:string):void {
    this.selectedSkills.push(skillString);
    this.memberProfile.skill_string = '';
    this.skillHints = [];
    this.skillString = '';
  }


  onSubmit():void {
    this.memberService.saveProfile(this.memberProfile, this.selectedSkills).subscribe(
      res => {
        console.log(res);
      }
    );
  }

}
```

Comment: did you see this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19549985/prevent-form-submission-on-enter-key

Comment: @Matthias: Yes, but: "this solution only works for buttons, but if you press "enter" in input-type-text field - you still have form sent." - I also already tried removing the submit button. No luck.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Try

```
<form (keydown.enter)="$event.target.tagName == 'TEXTAREA'" [formGroup]="profileForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit($event)">
```

It will also allow `enter` in `Textarea`s.

Comment: Just a hint. Returning `false` also calls `$event.preventDefault()`

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer thanks for reminding, lets make it more compact then

Comment: But now it doesn't return `false`. Perhaps `"!!($event.target.tagName == 'TEXTAREA)'"`(not sure about this `!!` operator - I'm not using JS/TS myself - only Dart)

Comment: I just tested, it's working for me. `$event.target.tagName == 'TEXTAREA'` is always a boolean, either `false` or `true`

Comment: Ah, sorry. You are right, I assumed this to be an assignment. Perhaps I need new glasses :D

Comment: haha, it's alright. I have learned enough from you to excuse you even without asking :)

Comment: I would also add BUTTON, `$event.target.tagName == 'TEXTAREA' || $event.target.tagName == 'BUTTON'`. Can happen you go through the form using TAB key and and up on button, then enter would not work.

Answer (score 7):

So the answer was actually quite simple... It wasn't `Event.preventDefault()` since I was listening for Enter on the input field and not the button. Removing `type="submit"` from the `button` wasn't enough since all buttons are type submit by default. The only change necessary was on the button element, adding `type="button"` explicitly and adding a `(click)` listener:

```
<button type="button" (click)="onSubmit()" class="btn btn-primary pull-right" [disabled]="!profileForm.valid">Save</button>
```

The only kind-of problem: Now submitting the form with enter never works. Would be a tiny bit more elegant to only prevent enter from submitting the form when the focus is in the autocomplete input field.

**Edit:**

To only prevent enter from submitting the form when the cursor is in the autocomplete field can be achieved by using Ankit Singh's solution and modifying it a bit:

```
<form [formGroup]="profileForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()" method="post" (keydown.enter)="$event.target.id != 'skill_string'" *ngIf="!showSuccessMessage">
```

(Note: The condition has to return false to prevent the default action to be triggered)

Of course we then need our regular submit button again (without the click event attached, or the form will submit twice):

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary pull-right" [disabled]="!profileForm.valid">Save</button>
```

You could also check the `event.target.classList` if you want to use a `.autocomplete` class. Or move the checking logic to a function into which you pass the `$event`.

Answer (score 2):

Events in Angular 2 behave like normal DOM events. To capture the event object, pass `$event` as a parameter in the event callback from the template:

Html:

```
<button (keyup.enter)="skillsHandleEnter($event, skillString)"></button>
```

JavaScript using [Event.preventDefault()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault):

```
@Component(...)
class MyComponent {
  skillsHandleEnter(event, skillString) {
    event.preventDefault();
    // ... your logic
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Prevent a form from submittion on <kbd>enter</kbd> or by clicking a `button`**

```
<textarea (keydown.enter)="provoked($event)"></textarea>

<button (keydown.enter)="provoked($event)" (click)="provoked($event)"></button>

provoked($event) {
   $event.preventDefault()
}
```

in case if you need to pass data to the method, then try

```
<textarea (keydown.enter)="provoked($event, data)"></textarea>

<button (keydown.enter)="provoked($event, data)" (click)="provoked($event, data)"></button>

provoked($event, data) {
   $event.preventDefault()

   // process the data here
}
```

Comment: You don't need or want to use `preventDefault()` on a textarea, and it wouldn't work even if it was an `<input>`. You can't use preventDefault like that. The form will completely ignore it.