# Angular stop Enter Key from submitting

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am trying to stop the <kbd>Enter</kbd> from submitting my button and rather make it point to another function. I tried trapping the <kbd>Enter</kbd> via the Host Listener and then do `preventDefault()` on it to stop it from firing.

My template in my component looks like this:

```
<mat-dialog-content class="dialog-content">{{data.content | translate}}</mat-dialog-content>
<div>
  <mat-button-toggle-group>
    <button type="button" matDialogClose (click)="dialogRef.close()">{{uppercase }}</button>
    <button type="button" (click)="dialogRef.close(true)" cdkFocusInitial>{{uppercase}}</button>
  </mat-button-toggle-group>
</div>
```

At the top of my component code:

```
export enum KEY_CODE {
  ENTER_KEY = 13
}
```

Inside my export class:

```
@HostListener('window:keyup', ['$event'])
keyEventUp(event: KeyboardEvent) {

    if (event.keyCode === KEY_CODE.ENTER_KEY) {
      event.preventDefault();
      event.stopPropagation();
      return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have submit on form?

Comment: @Vega no, I don't.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular 2: How to prevent a form from submitting on keypress enter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40909585/angular-2-how-to-prevent-a-form-from-submitting-on-keypress-enter)

Comment: @Mike McCaughan, there is no form here and it's about Angular Material Dialog

Answer (score 26, accepted):

DOM events carry a payload of information named $event. It's possible to use it on any input event, i.e. (input),(keydown), (click), etc.

It's possible to skip the use of the Hostlistner and apply preventDefault on $event, like so:

`(keydown.enter)="$event.preventDefault()"`

on the buttons:

```
...
<button ... (keydown.enter)="$event.preventDefault()" ...>...</button>
...
```

or:

HTML:

```
...
<button ... (keydown.enter)="prevent($event)" ...>...</button>
...
```

Typescript:

```
...
prevent(event){
 event.preventDefault();
}
...
```

**[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-9zwhfg)**

Comment: This is quite interesting.  How does the **$event** variable get defined in the code in the context of **(keydown.enter)**?

Comment: @AlanObject, DOM events carry a payload of information named $event. It's possible to use it on any input event, i.e. (input),(keydown), (click), etc.

Answer (score 8):

If you are using a form you can prevent it over all using `keydown.enter` event in the main tag:

```
<form [formGroup]="..." (keydown.enter)="$event.preventDefault()">
...
</form>
```

But maybe you want also to prevent some other keys combinations like:

```
(keydown.enter)="$event.preventDefault()"
(keydown.shift.enter)="$event.preventDefault()"
(keydown.control.enter)="$event.preventDefault()"
(keydown.alt.enter)="$event.preventDefault()"
```