# Prevent form submission with iOS return button

Tags: javascript, ios, angular, ionic-framework, ionic3

I have an `Ionic 3` application and running `iOS`, I found a bug that allows the user to submit a form even if the submit button is disabled. I've tried following this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19549985/prevent-form-submission-on-enter-key#), but no luck.

I have a temporary fix to alert user if the form fields are not filled out to prevent accidental submission, but it is a pain in itself.

I am only including the methods of the .ts file that are directly related to the submit button in the .html file.

The Screenshot shows the alert for submitting the form, but the button is still disabled.
[image: Button is disabled, but is triggered]

```js
// Adds chemicals to main BOL form
  addChemical(){

    const modal = this.modalCtrl.create(AddChemicalPage);

        modal.present();//presents the signature modal

         modal.onDidDismiss((returnParam: any) => {
           if(returnParam!=true){
             this.canSubmit = true;
             this.chemInfo.push(returnParam);
             /* Service that holds the list of chemicals user will be using **/
             this.reap.bolGlobalChemicals = this.chemInfo;

           }
           else{
             //console.log('backed out of no chemical!');
          }
         });
  }
  
destinationChange(e) {


      if(e.value == ""){
        this.destinationCitybol = false;
      }else{
        this.destinationCitybol = true;
      }
  }
  
yardChange(event: { component: SelectSearchableComponent, value: any }) {
       if(this.Shipper == null){
         this.Shipperbol = false;
       }else{
        this.Shipperbol = true;
       }

    }
    
checkstatusfinal(){
      if (this.Shipperbol && this.chemInfo.length != 0 && this.destinationCitybol){
        return true
      }
      else{
        return false
      }
    }
    
submitBOL(form: NgForm){
    //This is a temporary workaround
    var isFormFilled = this.checkstatusfinal();
    if(!isFormFilled){
      this.reap.presentAlert('Cannot Submit BOL','Please make sure the Shipper, Destination City, and at least 1 chemical is filled out before submitting,','Dismiss');
      return;
    }
}
```

```html
<ion-content>
  <form #form="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="submitBOL(form)" novalidate>
    <ion-item class="formField ionField">
      <ion-label stacked>Date</ion-label>
      <ion-datetime  [(ngModel)]="currentDate" displayFormat="MM/DD/YYYY" pickerFormat="MM/DD/YYYY" name="date" type="date" required></ion-datetime>
    </ion-item>

  <!-- data thrown into dropdown from API -->
    <ion-item>
      <ion-label stacked>Shipper</ion-label>
        <select-searchable
        [(ngModel)]="Shipper"
         item-content
         ngModel
         title="Yard"
         itemValueField=ID
         itemTextField=Name
         name="Shipper"
         [items]="yardsArray"
         [canSearch]="true"
         [canClear]="true"
         (onChange)="yardChange($event)"

         >
       </select-searchable>
    </ion-item>

    <!-- autofilled by API  based on user login-->
    <ion-item class="formField ionField">
      <ion-label stacked>Ship To/Driver</ion-label>
      <ion-input type="text" [(ngModel)]="driver" name="driver" value="{{this.driver}}" [disabled]="personnelArray"></ion-input>
    </ion-item>

  <ion-item class="formField ionField">
    <ion-label stacked>Destination City</ion-label>
      <ion-input type="text" [(ngModel)]="destinationCity" name="destinationCity"  (ionChange)="destinationChange($event)" required ></ion-input>
  </ion-item>

  <!-- data thrown into dropdown from API -->
    <ion-item>
      <ion-label stacked>Trailer</ion-label>
        <select-searchable
         item-content
         [(ngModel)]="Trailer"
         title="Trailer"
         itemValueField=ID
         itemTextField=Number
         name="Trailer"
         [items]="trailersArray"
         [canSearch]="true"
         [canClear]="true"
         (onChange)="trailerChange($event)">
       </select-searchable>
    </ion-item>
  <!-- data thrown into dropdown from API -->
    <ion-item>
      <ion-label stacked>Truck</ion-label>
      <select-searchable
         item-content
         [(ngModel)]= "Truck"
         title="Truck"
         itemValueField=ID
         itemTextField=Vehicle
         name="Truck"
         [items]="trucksArray"
         [canSearch]="true"
         [canClear]="true"
         (onChange)="truckChange($event)">
       </select-searchable>
    </ion-item>
      <!-- autofilled by sub form data-->
      <ion-label stacked>Chemical Requests</ion-label>
          <ion-grid *ngFor="let chem of chemInfo; let i = index">
            <div class="custChemicals">
                <ion-row>
                  <ion-col>Type of Package:</ion-col>
                  <ion-col>{{chem.Container?.Type}}</ion-col>
                </ion-row>
                <ion-row>
                  <ion-col>Stock Name:</ion-col>
                  <ion-col>{{chem.Product?.StockName}}</ion-col>
                </ion-row>
                <ion-row>
                  <ion-col>Number of Packages:</ion-col>
                  <ion-col>{{chem.noPackages}}</ion-col>
                </ion-row>
                <ion-row>
                  <ion-col> Gallons Out:</ion-col>
                  <ion-col>{{chem.Gallons}}</ion-col>
                </ion-row>
                <ion-row>
                  <ion-col class="center"><button (tap)="removeChemical(i)"ion-button class="trashButton"><ion-icon name="trash" ios="ios-trash" md="md-trash"></ion-icon></button></ion-col>
                </ion-row>
              </div>
          </ion-grid>
       <ion-grid>
        <ion-row>
          <ion-col  col-6 offset-3 text-center>
            <button id="chemicalButton" type="button"  (tap)="addChemical()" [disabled]="!checkstatus()"  ion-button icon-only clear large><ion-icon name="add-circle"></ion-icon></button>
          </ion-col>
        </ion-row>
      </ion-grid>
    <button id="submitButton" ion-button type="submit" block large [disabled]="!checkstatusfinal()">Submit</button>
  </form>
</ion-content>
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

How does accidental submission take place? Do you click on disabled button to see that happen?

What if instead of invoking an alert, you simply did:

```
submitBOL(form: NgForm){
    if(!this.checkstatusfinal()){
      return falase;
    }
}
```

Comment: No, when the user presses return on the iOS keyboard it automatically submits. Sorry, but I'm looking for an answer to solve this issue, not a workaround.